# Logger on the disk in Elixir

Tags: logging, erlang, elixir

I am using Elixir's default Logger Module for generating logs. However, I didn't find a way **to dump logs on the disk**. Is there any such facility in Logger Module? Or is there any other Elixir/Erlang Library which can be used for the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elixir includes a [`Logger`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/logger/Logger.html) library. Logger supports different backends where log messages are written to, however at the time being the only built-in backend is `:console`.

In the Erlang world, one of the well known logging libraries is [`Lager`](https://github.com/basho/lager). In fact, this library was also mentioned last year in a [discussion in the elixir-lang-core](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/jxcnTMgZ3OY) mailing list.

In the same thread there is also a mention to this project: [onkel-dirtus/logger_file_backend](https://github.com/onkel-dirtus/logger_file_backend). I haven't tried it yet, however it seems to be what you are looking for.

> `LoggerFileBackend`  is a custom backend for the elixir :logger application. However, unlike the default :console backend, we may want to configure multiple log files, each with different log levels formats, etc.

Comment: You can also just pipe the console output into a tool that does the file handling, log rotation and what not.

Comment: I already implemented logger_file_backend of onkel-dirtus. It works pretty good for me..thanks :)